# How to solve org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException error in spring boot and angular?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, post

I'm trying to send post request from angular 9 app to spring boot, here is the post request:

```
public createSuccessMessage(userId: number,tripName: string): Observable<any> {      
    return this.http.post(`${AppComponent.API}/Success/${userId}`, 
    {      
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Accept': 'text/plain', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' }),
      params: {        
        tripName: tripName
      },
      observe: 'response'
    });
  }
```

The tripName request param is not sent from some reason. Here is the code from the controller.

```
@PostMapping("/Success/{userId}")   
    public void createSuccessMessage(@PathVariable("userId") String userId, @RequestParam("tripName") String tripName) {    
        
        messagesService.createSuccessMessage(Long.valueOf(userId), tripName);       
    }
```

I'm getting a warning in the server side:

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required request parameter 'tripName' for method parameter type String is not present]
```

I've tried to send json, same result.

Answer (score 0):

@RequestParam is working only on Get request, changing to @GetRequest in the controller solve the problem.